# R cannot be resolved to a variable --

Tags: android, eclipse

```
package br.com.buceta;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String TAG = "bluetooth1";

  Button btnOn, btnOff;

  private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
  private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
  private OutputStream outStream = null;

  // SPP UUID service 
  private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

  // MAC-address of Bluetooth module (you must edit this line)
  private static String address = "00:15:FF:F2:19:5F";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); (error)

    btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOn); (error)
    btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOff); (error)

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    checkBTState();

    btnOn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        sendData("1");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});

btnOff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    sendData("0");
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn off LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
  }

  private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
      if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
          try {
          final Method  m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
          return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
      }
  }
  return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
super.onResume();

Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

// Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

// Two things are needed to make a connection:
//   A MAC address, which we got above.
//   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
//     UUID for SPP.

try {
    btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e1.getMessage() + ".");
    }

// Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
// when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

// Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
try {
  btSocket.connect();
  Log.d(TAG, "...Connection ok...");
} catch (IOException e) {
  try {
    btSocket.close();
  } catch (IOException e2) {
    errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
  }
}

// Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

try {
  outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
  errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
}
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
super.onPause();

Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

if (outStream != null) {
  try {
    outStream.flush();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to flush output stream: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
  }
 }

try     {
  btSocket.close();
} catch (IOException e2) {
  errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
}
      }

   private void checkBTState() {
// Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
// Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
    if(btAdapter==null) { 
  errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
} else {
  if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
  } else {
    //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
  }
}
  }

  private void errorExit(String title, String message){
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
finish();
  }

  private void sendData(String message) {
byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

Log.d(TAG, "...Send data: " + message + "...");

try {
  outStream.write(msgBuffer);
} catch (IOException e) {
  String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
  if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00")) 
    msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on line 35 in the java code";
    msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";

    errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);       
}
  }
}
```

There is no error in **R.layout.activity_main**, but the code can't recognize the buttons i have declared in **activity_main.xml**.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/btn_OFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnOff"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/btn_ON" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:src="@drawable/cxemnet_logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ps.: I solved the 'R cannot be resolved as a type' error by **Cleaning > Building project** and then this error appeared.

Comment: What do your import statements look like?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: btnOn cannot be resolved or is not a field and btnOff cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: You must declare btnOn and btnOff: `private Button btnOn; private Button btnOff;`

Comment: @user3179377 you can answer your own question the appropriate way... and then accept your own answer.

Comment: Remove `import br.com.buceta.R;`

Comment: ramaral the buttons are already declared

Comment: i removed import br.com.buceta.R; but the error persists

Comment: See if are not any error in xml files and clean you project again

Comment: Using Eclipse, so: save, build, clean, save, clean, build, use the handy "restart" option (yes, Eclipse is so flaky and people need to do this so often they built it right into the front end), clean, save, clean, pray, build, save, clean, build, uninstall eclipse, install Android Studio, import, build, run.

Comment: after clean the project 'setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);' presents error

Comment: Post all code for `activity_main.xml` and activity

Comment: what is the error in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: do you have the Project->build automatically option checked? Without that you need to build your project by hand

Comment: now, all the errors are: 'R cannot be resolved to a variable'

Comment: Try File/Restart on eclipse menu

Comment: search for `import android.R;`. If you find it, erase it. Sometimes eclipse imports that file by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your buttons. Either you declare them in your method

```
    ...
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnOn = findViewById(R.id.btnOn);
    Button btnOff = findViewById(R.id.btnOff);
    ...
```

or as a local field

```
    public class Classname { 

        private Button btnOn;
        private Button btnOff;

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete gen folder from project and then clean up the whole project also remove your import statement used for r.class used in activity class.

Answer (score 1):

Check your manifest file. You probably forgot to declare something. Usually an Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Android won't generate R file properly if there is any error in one of the XML files. Maybe the error is in one of them (i.e. the layout file): have you closed all tags? Is there any unsupported attribute?
Try also to organize imports (in windows the shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>MAIUSC</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> [it's a vocal, not zero], in Mac is <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>MAIUSC</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse added the "R" import automatically. Unless you are trying to reference resources from another package, it is unnecessary and can be deleted.

For example, if you have a package `com.package2` but your manifest has a package name of `com.package1` then any class in `com.package2` will need:

```
import com.package1.R;
```

In your case, it appears to be added automatically. Delete it (don't use "organize imports") and "clean"

Comment: if the import is not necessary and you use "organize imports", then eclipse will automatically delete that import. So, in my opinion, it's a good choice to use that.

Comment: Some versions / build files on Eclipse will throw an error when the "R" file is imported so "organize imports" may be fine. Regardless, getting a clean build is the important thing, and that import is the problem.